# Python + WebDriver -- No browser launched while using unittest module

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, python-unittest

Could you please help me with the next.
I found out the issue and could not resolve it.
When I am using next code, the browser has started and the test has passed:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("site URL")
```

BUT same with class and methods return message: "Process finished with exit code 0":

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
class GlossaryPage(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    def NoLorem(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("site URL")
    def tearDown(self):
        unittest.quit()
```

How can I get the browser opened using 2nd case (with methods and class)?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: For me `chromeOperator = GlossaryPage()` and `chromeOperator.setUp()` works just fine.

Comment: if you repalce `setUp` by `__init__` then, when creating an instance of `GlossaryPage` it will open a browser

Comment: no it's unittest specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While working through Python's **unittest** module with *Selenium* you have to consider a few facts as follows :

- While you pass the *Key* `executable_path` provide the *Value* through single quotes along with the raw `r` switch.
- While you define the `@Tests` name the tests starting with **test** e.g. **def test_NoLorem(self):**
- While you invoke `get()` ensure you are passing a valid `url` e.g. **http://www.python.org**
- While you invoke the `quit()` method within `def tearDown(self):` invoke the method through the *WebDriver* instance as `self.driver.quit()`.
- If you are using **unittest** module you have to call the `Tests` through **if __name__ == "__main__":**
- Here is your own code with the required minor modifications :

  ```
  import unittest
  from selenium import webdriver

  class GlossaryPage(unittest.TestCase):

      def setUp(self):
          self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
          self.driver.maximize_window()
          self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
      def test_NoLorem(self):
          driver = self.driver
          driver.get("http://www.python.org")
      def tearDown(self):
          self.driver.quit()

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      unittest.main()
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure as I haven't tested it but I suspect the browser is still opened from the first code. So what I suggest here is to use `driver.close()` to terminate the process properly once you get out of script.

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("site URL")
driver.close()  # Must be there
```

Similarly, you can make modification in the test script to put `self.driver.close()` in the `tearDown` method.

Comment: Check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281806/python-opening-multiple-tabs-using-selenium), probably it will help

Comment: Help with what? I have no problem :)

Comment: Thought its OP who replied here. Never mind ignore my comments. and yes you are correct it will just keep open one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

In unittest, you have to put the tested code in method called

```
test_<custom_text_here>
```

Moreover I believe you wanted to quit the driver and not unittest?
Try to replace the line

```
unittest.quit()
```

With

```
self.driver.close()
```