# AttributeError: 'GoogleSearch' object has no attribute 'driver' while executing tests through Python unittest

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, python-unittest

I use this post http://www.autotest.org.ua/first-autotest-with-selenium-webdriver-and-python/ and made project in PyCharm

[image: This is a photo]

Code trials:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


class GoogleSearch(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUpp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Python37-32\geckodriver-v0.23.0-win64\geckodriver.exe")
        self.driver.get('https://www.google.by')
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    def test_01(self):
        driver = self.driver
        input_field = driver.find_element_by_class_name('class="gLFyf gsfi"')
        input_field.send_keys('python')
        input_field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Errors:

```
FAILED (errors=1)

Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\unittest\case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\unittest\case.py", line 615, in run
    testMethod()
  File "D:\QA\untitled\test.py", line 13, in test_01
    driver = self.driver
AttributeError: 'GoogleSearch' object has no attribute 'driver'


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I dont understand how to fix it...

Answer (score -1):

This error message...

```
AttributeError: 'GoogleSearch' object has no attribute 'driver'
```

...implies that the **unittest** have an initialization error.

I don't see any such error in your code block as such but there is an issue in the `setUp()` method. A few words:

- `def setUp(self):`: The *`setUp()`* is the part of initialization and this method will get called before every test function which you are going to write in this testcase class. You have misspelt `setUp(self)` as **`setUpp(self)`**.
- If you are using `webdriver.Chrome()` you need to pass the *absolute path* of the **chromedriver** but you have provided **geckodriver**.
- While you pass the *Key* `executable_path` provide the *Value* through single quotes along with the raw `r` switch.
- `def tearDown(self):`: The *`tearDown()`* method is called after every test method. This is the method to do all the cleanup actions.
- `if __name__ == '__main__':`: This line sets the `__name__` variable to have a value `"__main__"`. If this file is being imported from another module then `__name__` will be set to the other module's name.
- You will find a detailed discussion in [What does if **name** == “**main**”: do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do?)
- With the above mentioned points, your effective code block will be:

  ```
  import unittest
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

  class GoogleSearch(unittest.TestCase):

      def setUp(self):
          self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
          self.driver.get('https://www.google.by')
          self.driver.maximize_window()
          self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)

      def test_01(self):
          driver = self.driver
          input_field = driver.find_element_by_class_name('class="gLFyf gsfi"')
          input_field.send_keys('python')
          input_field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

      def tearDown(self):
          self.driver.quit()

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      unittest.main()
  ```
- You can find a relevant discussion in [Python + WebDriver — No browser launched while using unittest module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859370/python-webdriver-no-browser-launched-while-using-unittest-module/49860022#49860022)