# open multiple chrome profile with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, path

when I run this code with chrome already open I get this error:
Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir

I need to have multiple profiles open at the same time, what can I do?

```html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\utent\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Profile 3")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Development\chromedriver.exe', options=options)

driver.get("https://www.instagram.com")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python -- Opening multiple tabs using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281806/python-opening-multiple-tabs-using-selenium)

Comment: A profile is associated one-to-one per selenium web driver. You should instantiate multiple selenium driver per profile

Comment: @tbhaxor thanks for the answer, I tried to create 2 folders with chromedriver inside, and put the 2 paths inside the codes, but it gives me the same error ... what exactly do you mean by instantiate multiple selenium driver per profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user-data directory get locked by the first instance and the second instance fails with exception
So the solution is to create a Userdata for each profile

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\anyPathWhereYouWantToSaveYourUserData\\profile1")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Windows\System32\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com")
```

No worries you can access your new profiles now manually if you would like to just by creating shortcuts you just need to add to your target in your shortcut

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir="C:\anyPathWhereYouWantToSaveYourUserData\profile1"
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you want to open two chrome profiles

You need to instantiate two web drivers with the profile you want to set.

From instantiate I meant, you need to create two chrome web drivers because once the options are set and you have created the *driver*, you cannot change this later

So,

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = [Options(), Options()]
options[0].add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\utent\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
options[1].add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\utent\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")

options[0].add_argument("--profile-directory=Profile 3")
options[1].add_argument("--profile-directory=Profile 4") # add another profile path

drivers = [webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Development\chromedriver.exe', options=options[0]), webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Development\chromedriver.exe', options=options[1])]

drivers[0].get("https://instagram.com")
drivers[1].get("https://instagram.com")
```